# Silverlight OOB Application Path Portability

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

Silverlight Out-of-browser applications get installed to a seemingly random location:

AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\2333572144.www.microsoft.com

for example.

Currently, I am simply storing this path, which works perfectly well on a single machine and a single install, but how can I refer to this application between different installations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is interested:

I was able to use the OriginalSourceUri property in the Silverlight app's metadata to uniquely identify and locate apps in an installation-directory-agnostic way.

Comment: Does it hold up over time?  I used a ClickOne app in WPF and that folder location wasn't consistant and it wasn't up dateable.

Comment: For my purposes, it has been reliable. The OriginalSourceUri points to the web address where the xap file was downloaded from. And thats what I was looking for, a way to identify an app independent of where it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access the path outside of the isolated storage interface in the application, the path isn't necessarily portable.